# Why gatsby-plugin-manifest cannot resolve 'gatsby'?

Tags: reactjs, plugins, progressive-web-apps, gatsby

I'm developing a website using Gatsby and some plugins, but this site needs to have some progressive web apps features and as I read the docs you must install gatsby-plugin-manifest and gatsby-plugin-offline.

Since I installed gatsby-plugin-manifest, It only gives me a lot of error... which I couldn't even downgrade some past versions I couldn't make it work.

The error is the following one:

```
Error: Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'gatsby' in /Users/evandro/workspace/evansantos.github.io/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-manifest
resolve module gatsby in /Users/evandro/workspace/evansantos.github.io/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-manifest
[/Users/evandro/workspace/evansantos.github.io/node_modules/gatsby/index.js.jsx]
  @ ./~/gatsby-plugin-manifest/gatsby-ssr.js 7:14-31

➜  git:(master) ✗
```

Comment: Have you globally installed gatsby first?

Comment: Yes, I did Tom.
In fact, I was using Gatsby 1.9.247 instead of 2.0.7 
now it's working, thank you, Tom, for giving me a tip of what could be

Comment: Can you show your `package.json`? I think gatsby should be installed locally and not globally.

Comment: Did you install the `gatsby-plugin-manifest` plugin into your npm modules like so: `npm install --save gatsy-plugin-manifest`?

Comment: Can you try deleting your node_modules folder, and install again? And yeah, it does need to be installed locally as well. But npm should take care of this. Gatsby is a dependency of gatsby-plugin-manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command in terminal:

```
npm install -g gatsby-cli
```